# Probability square of a normal is in a range; mode of gamma

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution, mode

> 1. If $X \sim N(1,4)$ find $\mathbb{P}(1<X^2<9)$
> 2. If $x=2$ is the unique mode of the $X \sim \Gamma(2,\beta)$ distribution, find the parameter $\beta$.

Well I tried transformation to solve this problem.
Set $Y=X^2$ and I actually found the pdf of $Y$ but when I try to calculate $\mathbb{P}(1<X^2<9)$, I just can't calculate because the pdf of $Y$ is so complicated to integral 1 to 9.

and in number 2. I think I didn't understand the question properly. Does the mode mean that 'the number that came out most'?

I understand the question as like something that if $X\sim \Gamma(r/2,2)$ it follows $X \sim X^2(r)$.

Comment: 1. is find P(1<X-square<9)

Comment: The $x=2$ is unnecessary, just remove it and the sentence becomes $X \sim \Gamma(2,\beta)$ is the unique mode... which actually makes sense. Now, just look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution, use the $\Gamma(k,\theta)$ definition. BTW, this looks like coursework, and if it is, you have to put in the `self-study` tag, and ask questions that do not ask for answers, but just help clarifying where you have gotten stuck, which is all I am allowed to answer here.

Comment: @Carl, no, your suggested change doesn't make sense; the original is a little clumsily worded but is clear enough; your change omits something important. I'll make an edit to clarify it.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, i use this site first time, and i didn't know how this site goes. anyway i can't see what is the unique thing in X~Gamma(2,Beta), i try to use axioms of probability to find out Beta, but it goes to 1 regardless of Beta value :(

Comment: @tae11 Your second question was somewhat confusing; I have edited to clarify what I believe was intended. However, as it stands your question doesn't follow our rules. See the [help/on-topic] under *homework* (whether or not it's literally homework). In particular, you'll need to show what you tried and specifically ask about where you had trouble.

Comment: yeah i try to put it under self-study tag, but they keep saying that i need '300 reputation' to do that. BTW thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need 300 reputation to add the tag to your question, you need 300 reputation to *create* a tag. If you're trying to create a tag you're typing it wrong. Since you're trying to add it, I'll fix that part for you (edit: I have added the tag for you), but complying with the other requirements is more important. You'll need to edit your question.

Comment: oh now i got it. anyway i or you (not sure) put self-study tag for this question :) I will keep that in mind

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried. You also need to clarify which parameterization of the gamma you're using. Some hints to get you started: on 1. what values of $X$ satisfy the condition? On 2., write the density in terms of $\beta$ (and draw it if you don't already know what it looks like). Now where's the mode in terms of $\beta$?

Comment: Look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and modify your questions to request help only as is allowed in the rules. BTW, @Glen_b yup, a spot of work I put in for this, thanks for yours, too.

Comment: @Carl i edited the question as you suggested. i hope it fit with the rules now :)

Comment: Yes, possibly. I nominated it for a reopening, but I'm finished for the night. I'll look in again tomorrow.

Comment: Your question about what the mode is indicates a [lack of research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). See the last sentence of the first paragraph in the wikipedia article on the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). In addition, as already requested above, in your question, *write down the density of the gamma* so we can see what parameterization you're working with (it will also help you to do this)

Answer (score 6):

1. *Don't* compute the distribution of $X^2$. Instead (as I already suggested) simply identify *all* the values of $X$ that satisfy the condition (i.e. work directly with the distribution of $X$). You could do it by computing the distribution of the square but it's effort you don't really need to go to.
2. The mode according to the wikipedia article on it:

   > The mode of a continuous probability distribution is the value $x$ at which its probability density function has its maximum value.

   The density function for a gamma with shape parameter 2 is *easy* to write down. When finding modes you can safely ignore normalizing constants and work with an unnormalized density, making it easier still.

   As I already suggested, figure out where the maximum of that density function is. It's pretty simple -- there's a unique global maximum (which is also the only local maximum and even the only turning point). The density has properties that make this a particularly simple task.

General guidance: in both cases, *draw* a picture.

Comment: thanks. i got the answer by differentiating the f(x) to find mode in #2.

Comment: and for #1, i thought about the domain of X, and find out the range for it :)
thanks!